# What does `env COLUMNS=%S ps …` do?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have seen the syntax `env COLUMNS=%s`in shell scripts, e.g. see the line below from the [Helm package](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-sys.el) in Emacs:

```
env COLUMNS=%s ps -axo pid,user,pri,nice,ucomm,tty,start,vsz,%%cpu,%%mem,etime,command
```

What does `env COLUMNS=%s` do? How is it different for example from `COLUMNS=%s` or `export COLUMNS=%s` ?

Finally, does anyone know if such syntax is supported in OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does env COLUMNS=%s do?

It passes the variable `COLUMNS` with the value `%s` to the `ps` command and *forgets*, i.e. the variable does not affect the subsequent commands.

`export` would cause the variable to be available for subsequent commands too which may or may not be the intent.

Saying:

```
FOO=bar command
```

and

```
env FOO=bar command
```

are identical.  However, `env` allows an option `-i` that causes it to ignore the environment that it inherits.

Answer (score 4):

The following three shell snippets are equivalent (as in, they accomplish the same thing, and you have to dig in to observe any different effect):

```
env COLUMNS=%s ps …
```

```
COLUMNS=%s ps …
```

```
(export COLUMNS=%s; ps …)
```

All of them set the environment variable `COLUMNS` to the value `%s` for the invocation of the `ps` command. In the shell, the value of `COLUMNS`, if any, remains the same as before. The first snippet accomplishes this effect through the external program `env`, the second using pure shell syntax, the third through the `export` shell builtin combined with the `(…)` subshell construct.

This is different from

```
export COLUMNS=%s; ps …
```

which would set the environment variable `COLUMNS` in a way that remains in effect in the remainder of the script, and from

```
COLUMNS=%s; ps …
```

which unlike the others sets only a shell variable (which `ps` won't see), but does not export `COLUMNS` to the environment. (However, if `COLUMNS` was already present in the environment, it is set to `%s`.)

The program `env` may look useless, but it exists

- because it's older than the `VAR=value command` shell construct;
- because it's useful in other cases, for example when a program starts another program without going through a shell and you want to set a few environment variables;
- because it can work systems that have a different shell (e.g. in csh, or on Windows), as long as the `env` command is available and in the PATH.

All the constructs mentioned here work in any Bourne/POSIX-style shell (sh, ash, bash, ksh, zsh, …), except a few antique Bourne shell versions that you're unlikely to ever encounter (and that have never been ported to Linux or OSX).

Note that `COLUMNS` should be a number; `ps` ignores it if it isn't numeric. Zsh even refuses to set `COLUMNS` to a non-numeric value, because it declares `COLUMNS` as a numeric variable by default. In the program you're quoting, `%s` will be replaced by a number before the string is used as a shell command.